# C#: In a KeyDown event, what should I use to check what key is down?

Tags: c#, keyboard

In a KeyDown event, I have the KeyEventArgs to work with. It has (among other things) these three properties:

- `e.KeyCode`
- `e.KeyData`
- `e.KeyValue`

Which one should I use for what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Somehow I misread your question to include checking a valid character. Did you modify it? I've added a description of each.

- **KeyCode** is the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration value for the key that is down
- **KeyData** is the same as KeyCode, but combined with any SHIFT/CTRL/ALT keys
- **KeyValue** is simply an integer representation of KeyCode

If you *just* need the character, I'd probably recommend using the KeyPress event and using the [KeyPressEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx).[KeyChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property. You can then use [Char.IsLetterOrDigit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) to find out if it's a valid character.

Alternatively, you might be able to cast [KeyEventArgs.KeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) to a char and then use Char.IsLetterOrDigit on that.

Comment: I don't agree... You are assuming that the user does not want to catch any modifiers and his input is limited to keyboard ASCII.

Comment: IsLetterOrDigit uses CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory if the character is not latin.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I decided I should split it up, since I wanted to know this as well, but more in a general sense :)

Comment: Tested the IsLetterOrDigit now, and it works like it should. Both with regular ascii keys, norwegian æ, ø and å letters, and when combining an accent key with another. Like ¨ + o = ö. Perfect!

Comment: I also did validation against some russian and greek characters and it worked fine.

Comment: Sweet! I find it amusing that you edit your original answer to incorporate other answers, thus giving the impression that your original answer was comprehensive/complete.

Comment: Actually, I had added in the first major addition (the list) before I saw your answer. I won't deny that they are similar, though.

Comment: Thanks for the list with simple descriptions.  I thought that's what the difference between KeyCode and KeyData, but why couldn't MSDN just say so?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `KeyCode` property to check against the `Keys` enumeration for most operations. However some of the basic differences below might help you to better decide which one you need for your situation.

Differences:

- `KeyCode` - Represents the `Keys` enumeration value that represents the key that is currently in Down state.
- `KeyData` - Same as `KeyCode`, except that it has additional information in the form of modifiers - Shift/Ctrl/Alt etc.
- `KeyValue` - The numeric value of the `KeyCode`.

Comment: But KeyCode and KeyData has the same type, Keys enumeration. I can't find any extra there?

Comment: It will only be different if a key modifier (shift/alt/ctrl) is down.

Comment: ooh, cause its a flags thing?

Comment: Yep, 'coz it's a Flags "thing"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Very basic using of KeyDown

```
   private void tbSomeText_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B && e.Modifiers != Keys.Shift) {

            MessageBox.Show("You Pressed b");
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift) {
            MessageBox.Show("You Pressed Shift+A");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564358/c-activate-a-textbox-when-user-starts-typing/564387#564387) to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564358/c-activate-a-textbox-when-user-starts-typing):

Use the [KeyPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564358/c-activate-a-textbox-when-user-starts-typing) event.

Quoting MSDN:

> A KeyPressEventArgs specifies the character that is composed when the user presses a key. For example, when the user presses SHIFT + K, the KeyChar property returns an uppercase K.

This way you don't need to mess around with `e.KeyCode`, 
`e.KeyData` and
`e.KeyValue`.

Comment: Yeah, accepted your answer in the other question. But here I was more looking for a general explanation of their uses. Which is why I split it up. Something which I came to think about juuust when I clicked the submit button, so, sorry about the confusion =)