# C#: Activate a TextBox when user starts typing

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, keyboard, focus

I want to activate a search textbox when the user starts to type something (even if the textbox isnt focused right then). I have come as far as setting `KeyPreview` on the form to `true`. Then in the KeyDown event handler, I have this:

```
if(!searchTextBox.Focused)
{
    searchTextBox.Focus();
}
```

This almost works. The textbox is focused, but the first typed letter is lost. I guess this is because the textbox never really gets the event, since it wasn't focused when it happend. So, do anyone have a clever solution to how I could make this work like it should?

I would also like some tips to how make this only happen when regular keys are pressed. So not like, arrow keys, modifier keys, function keys, etc. But this I will probably figure out a way to do. The previous issue on the other hand, I am not so sure how I should tackle...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an addition to the answer from SDX2000, have a look at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) for the KeyDown event. It also refers to the [KeyPressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx) event, which is fired after the KeyDown event, I think it is better suited for what you want to do.

Quoting MSDN:

> A KeyPressEventArgs specifies the character that is composed when the user presses a key. For example, when the user presses SHIFT + K, the KeyChar property returns an uppercase K.

```
private void YourEventHandler(object Sender, KeyPressEventArgs Args)
{
    if(!searchTextBox.Focused)
    {
        searchTextBox.Focus();
        searchTextBox.Text += Args.KeyChar;
        // move caret to end of text because Focus() selects all the text
        searchTextBox.SelectionStart = searchTextBox.Text.Length
    }
}
```

I'm actually not certain that you can use `+=` to append a char to a string, so you need to check on that. And I don't know what happens when the user hits `return`, better follow up an that issue as well.

Comment: += seems to work. Although the property is called Text, not Value. So you could maybe fix that in your example :)

Comment: Also, I had to add searchTextBox.SelectionStart = searchTextBox.Text.Length on the end, cause when I Focus() it selects all the text. So when the user continues to type, it all goes away.. :p Other than that, this totally works :)

Comment: the SelectionStart line needs to be the last one to work properly =)

Comment: Now that you mention it... fixed my answer (again)

Answer (score 3):

You will get the first key stroke as part of the KeyDown event. You can save it to the textbox yourself.

Comment: But how does this work with non-ascii letters and stuff? Especially thinking of various modifier keys etc being used...